# What content-type's execute javascript in the browser?

Tags: javascript, http, browser

The page you are viewing right now has the HTTP header element of `Content-type: text/html`.  HTML displayed normally and JavaScript will be executed.  If you have a `Content-Type: text/javascript`  then the JavaScript **is not executed**,  it is only [displayed](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js).

My question is:  Are there content-type's other than `text/html` that will execute JavaScript? I wold like as complete of a list as possible for any common browser (IE,Firefox,Chrome,Safari).

Comment: Maybe you mean which contents types are capable of making javascript execute? Because text/html doesn't execute jasvascript, the <script> tag within the document is one of the execution triggers. Keep in mind this list is potentially limitless when you consider browser plugins and extensions.

Comment: @Rook Are you searching for an alternative?

Comment: @Šime Vidas @chris I need a list of all them,  this is for QA purposes.

Comment: @Rook Note that different browsers likely recognize different content types. I wouldn't be surprised if there is a big difference between IE and Safari (on Mac). Are you interested in a specific browser?

Comment: @Šime Vidas  Any of the common browsers.

Comment: @chris Your are totally right,  and a few thousand lines of code have been written which do just that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of a full list, and it may well be that no such list exists publicly. You may have to find out for yourself. (Although I don't think anything speaks against setting up a test page with a number of iframes, and asking the SO community to provide data with their respective browsers. It's been done before.)

In Internet Explorer, this one should definitely be on the list:

- `application/hta` for [Hypertext Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Candidates that I would test for (because it's conceivable a careless programmer might activate them for HTML parsing) include:

- `application/form-data`
- `text/xhtml+xml` (used to be [proposed](http://www.imc.org/ietf-xml-mime/mail-archive/msg00615.html) in 2000, no idea what happened to that)

However, I tested those with both Chrome 9 and the latest Firefox, and they reject everything except `text/html`. Firefox shows them as downloadable resources instead, which I think eliminates them from your equation as any JS therein will be executed in the local context rather than the URL's. (IE is executing everything including text/plain for me, but I think that is a header mixup with my server.)

If you want to go for hard-core sure for the Open Source browsers, check their source code or ask on their mailing lists/forums. I have a feeling the good ones have `text/html` hard-coded.

**Edit: Arrgh**! Firefox, Chrome and IE parse HTML, and execute scripts, regardless of content type - I successfully managed to set `Content-type: text/poppycock` - **when the resource's extension is .htm or .html**. That means that you have to test not only for MIME types, but for file extensions (which should not play any role in HTTP) as well. Didn't know that - this was probably introduced to fix the output of broken web servers. Stuff like this is why I don't work in IT security :)

All tests made on Windows 7.

Comment: File extensions generally doesn't matter, if the `Content-Type` is unrecognized browsers may resort to MIME-sniffing: https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/

Answer (score 2):

`application/xhtml+xml` would have to execute Javascript. That's the only one I can think of at the top of my head.

Answer (score 2):

This wouldn't be very useful. Javascript has no way to import other scripts, so your script would be isolated from libraries. The only way to tie them together is through HTML. Also, the input/output options are very limited without a document.

Comment: Oh ok :) That sounds interesting. What are they?

Answer (score 1):

[PDF files can also execute javascript](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/applying-actions-scripts-pdfs.html#about_javascript_in_acrobat) (`application/pdf`).

Aswell as XML documents (`application/xml`), including SVG (`image/svg+xml`), for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<document>
<script xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" src="xml.js"></script>
</document>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `application/javascript`?