# Prevent IE from auto-detecting MIME type

Tags: internet-explorer, file-upload, mime-types

I'm using [this](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) file uploader in a website. It uses AJAX for Chrome, Firefox, etc, and a hidden iframe for IE. I'm having an issue with returning data (XML) from the servlet that accepts the file, to the webpage. Using the AJAX method works fine, but using an iframe, IE (need support for at least IE 8) auto-detects the mime type of the XML (which is put into the iframe), and embeds it in HTML as if it were being displayed. I've tried explicitly setting the Content-Type on the server (text/plain: overruled by IE's detection; embedded in JSON with a mime type of application/json: asks to download json). I just want the raw XML, is there any way to prevent IE from modifying it, or should I go some other route?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This isn't a programming issue so much as how to make IE 8 behave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out: **`Iframe.contentDocument.XMLDocument`** will give you the raw XML.

Strangely, the XMLDocument property doesn't show up in IE 8's debugger, which is why I missed it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I think IE switches to this behaviour based on file *extension*. (It's dumb and goes against the concept of HTTP URLs for which the extension is supposed to be meaningless, but [all browsers seem to do similar things with the `.html` extension.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741438/what-content-types-execute-javascript-in-the-browser/4756978#4756978))

Try changing the file extension to, say, `.xmls` or `.xml.txt`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm only concerned with the server to client data, which is just raw XML sent over the wire, not a file.

Comment: @Ryan how are you sending this? How are you injecting it into the iframe? Probably needs some code.