# Stylesheet appearing corrupt on server

Tags: wordpress, apache, file-upload

I have a Wordpress site which seems to have suddenly stopped working.
The stylesheets have become scrambled when viewed on the browser sort of like this:

> ‹������Œ“ËNÜ0†_Åê¦&Qf`6aEHH´bÁ8ñ™øÇŽlg:4Ê»ã”Ü/nÿüçöû!ä;.—äÊ¢ƒG°©ÁÂ¡V×­æÕ: ½b‘CÂÌL,“uáAfC&âvÞöAŸ‰DÂz½ÐÖýb§A¹r,û!uÉI){-ÕyÊI´Î—÷Å­|_:¡Í½âÌÁüã0   U–°ô½ozÔÚù%Ã‚eðÒt.e%�3áâÝ·ºs`|âbG[Hö£’¨
>   ŸòÜæ÷q²$žA•hçtûâ\Ïï¯
>   Æ¹ß9pºˆwÑŠão’U3#èö¾‰†Í-0“Š&ñ¤ôcTÕ4ŠFë¢ò÷Wúæ(õïX ç
>   êYæOÚä“UöãUF¦nJw}"uú~—J¿Eìï}b'ÌXƒáôÄCq¾ë„6˜ÃaíìãÉgi&åQM<ît‹wºž®OÈÓ
>   æé6ôt‹zºÄžþÇU0B’^xÙ®»ó1tî‚”öÙ^¾þ§Å3ÔkÆ‰ë6šº8<ÛW
>   ~luÔÊÿ@¼{.A{ib´°ütt›º²ýø–¯ìˆ¸  ØRºe6³O���ÿÿ�O¶ÅãY��

The rest of my site seems fine but appears style-less.

I've tried uploading the stylesheets again but the same thing happens when I try to look at them directly through the browser.

If I download them off the server through Filezilla they seem completely fine though.

Anyone have any ideas what's going on?

**HTTP response header:**

> Name  Value   Delim Status: HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Wed, 08 Aug 2012
>   00:30:11 GMT   Server:    Apache   Last-Modified: Tue, 07 Aug 2012 03:46:49
>   GMT    Vary:  Accept-Encoding,User-Agent   Content-Encoding:  gzip
>   Cache-Control:    public   Expires:   A604800  Content-Length:    4544
>   Connection:   close    Content-Type:  text/css     Content-Language:  en-US

Comment: What browser are you using? Does this happen in other browsers? My guess is the file is being compressed by the server on sending and is being shown raw (browser doesn't uncompress). Chrome sometimes does this, but it may be an issue with your server config. Can you post the response headers for the request?

Comment: I'm using Chrome but same happens in Firefox and Internet Explorer.
I've added the response headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what caused it but saved all my settings and images/info and deleted my Wordpress and reinstalled it and it's working again as it should.

Don't have any idea why this started happening, only thing I can think of is I installed a few plugins the night before.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug filed in the Filezilla Trac which is identical to your issue:

http://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/6505

http://trac.filezilla-project.org/attachment/ticket/6505/FileUploadIssue.png

The bug is not resolved, but the report gives this work-around:

> I downloaded another free FTP Client (Core FTP Lite) and the same
>   files and directories were uploaded once again with successful results

If you want to get to the bottom of this, I would suggest starting by trying different character encoding on your stylesheets (and check if other text files download like this).

As an alternative workaround (and also a way to test if it's a server issue or Filezilla) make a php file that echos the contents of the stylesheet. I would think that if Wordpress is working, the strange encoding issue is probably an issue with Apache's file handling configuration. This would work around that by using PHP to handle the file reading and output instead of Apache:

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents('style.css');
```

---

**Edit:**

If this PHP work-around works, you could try [setting the type handler for .css files to PHP in a .htaccess file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413107/headercontent-type-text-css-is-working-in-ff-cr-but-in-ie9-it-shows-up-as#5703588). This is a pretty dirty trick though; you should probably talk to your host about the issue before resorting to this.

Comment: Good idea but I've directly re-uploaded the files through cPanel and it's still not having it. I tried uploading it to a different folder inside my Wordpress themes folder but get a 500 Internal Server Error so I'm starting to think it's got something to do with Wordpress' settings

Comment: what happens if you create a new file through cpanel's file manager and put some content in it? Does it have the same issue? Unless you're using a plugin to manage your stylesheets, they're generally accessed directly as files. **Edit:** I see this is fixed - great!

Comment: I tried all that through cPanel and the stylesheet would look fine when I opened it in the file manager but would still mess up when I tried to open it directly through the browser. The only thing I can think that might've caused it was a dodgy Wordpress plugin... Thank you for all your help though, it is very appreciated!