# Styling the comments of a post on WP

Tags: php, html, css

I can't stylize the elements that only show on the page when it has comments (`<comments>`,`<commentlist>` etc) with the CSS file. I got it to work like

```
<?php here it calls the comments if any ?>
<style>
 .comments{}
</style>
```

I would like to know why this happens and if there is any better way to deal with this.
Thanks

Derik

Comment: You should not need to dynamically add your CSS. Does the style of the page change if you have comments? Perhaps a bit more code would help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to dynamically add CSS by PHP.

If you are not using the [`header(“Content-type: text/css”);`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413107/headercontent-type-text-css-is-working-in-ff-cr-but-in-ie9-it-shows-up-as) before output, then CSS, which has been dynamically produced, will slow down your page. It will behave as internal CSS, therefore the better solution is to cache it.