# Concatenate css with php in link meta stylesheet

Tags: php, css, concatenation, httprequest, css-frameworks

What is the way to concatenate multiple css files into one line with php?

I want to reduce the following ..

```
<link href="reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link href="grid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link href="commons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

into

```
<link href="concatenator.php+reset.css+grid.css+commons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

the result one css or html file with all stylesheet inside

This method reduce the http requests, and have other features for designer and developer with use dinamyc sites configurations.

Comment: Your URL should be more like `concatenator.php?files=reset,grid,commons`. And the famous concatenator.php if just a little script that will explode the `files` value, retrieve each file content to finally echo them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code posted by MatRt is close, but is using + signs instead of . signs for the appending and it doesn't seem to actually send the CSS to the page, even though it will print the CSS.

I managed to get the code supplied here working with a small tweak to it. Here it is:

```html
<?php

// Check the parameter and stop if there is no files param
if (empty($_GET['files']))
    die();

// Retrieve the list of files
$files = explode(",", $_GET['files']);
$directoryOfCss = 'C:\xampplite\htdocs\path\to\my\folder\css\\';
$cssContent = "";

// Loop on all potential file and try to retrieve its content
foreach($files as $oneFile)
{
 //echo $directoryOfCss . $oneFile . ".css";
    if (file_exists($directoryOfCss . $oneFile . ".css")){
     //echo $directoryOfCss . $oneFile . ".css<br>";
        $cssContent .= file_get_contents($directoryOfCss . $oneFile . ".css");
    }
}

// Finally echo the total content of CSS
header("Content-Type: text/css"); 
header("X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff");
header("Content-Type: text/css;X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff;");
echo $cssContent;
```

I got the headers part from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413107/headercontent-type-text-css-is-working-in-firefox-and-chrome-but-in-inter).

Comment: I added some minification too by replacing the $cssContent line with this: `$cssContent .= preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',file_get_contents($directoryOfCss . $oneFile . ".css"));`

Answer (score 1):

Your URL should be more like

```
concatenator.php?files=reset,grid,commons
```

*Note*: you can chose other separator if you don't like the `,`

And the famous `concatenator.php` could be like

```
<?php

// Check the parameter and stop if there is no files param
if (empty($_GET['files']))
    die();

// Retrieve the list of files
$files = explode(",", $_GET['files']);
$directoryOfCss = "/absolute/path/to/your/css/files/";
$cssContent = "";

// Loop on all potential file and try to retrieve its content
foreach($files as $oneFile)
{
    if (file_exists($directoryOfCss + $oneFile + ".css"))
        $cssContent += file_get_contents($directoryOfCss + $oneFile + ".css");
}

// Finally echo the total content of CSS
echo $cssContent;
```

Comment: hi MatRt thanks for respond but your code is not showing nothing the echo is blank, i cannot find the problem

Comment: did you replace `/absolute/path/to/your/css/files/` with the good value .? the code is very basic and should work. How is you `<link>` ?