# Can't set header to text/css in php

Tags: php, html

```
header("Content-type: text/css");
echo 'sometext';
exit;
```

in my browser I still see the type text/html, why is that?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Could it be because it is not valid CSS and therefore the browser sets it to the default `text/html` (I don't know, just worth a try)?

Comment: Are you sure there's no other output with a silent "headers already sent" error message?

Comment: @jori: that's not the server or browser's problem. if you say the content is text/css, that'll be the header. Whether the actual response body contains CSS or something entirely different is not up to the http layer to determine.

Comment: Yes, I know that should be the behavior, but it is at least worth a try. Oh hell, i'll try it myself, 1 sec...

Comment: jori is right, it could depend on where you look for the content-type. (I dont use google-chrome, so im not sure if that could be)

Comment: Well FF showed nicely `text/css`, but I can't find any MIME information in Chrome. Perhaps to better help the questioner he should answer how this is a problem for him? Also when inspecting elements in both FF and Chrome, the the contents of your CSS file is actually formatted using HTML. It seems that both use 'CSS code' to HTML rendering for display purposes. Perhaps here is the error?

Comment: i think i have found related question about your concern
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413107/headercontent-type-text-css-is-working-in-ff-cr-but-in-ie9-it-shows-up-as

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments already say it, but try to print/echo some real css-content. if your file is still detected as text/html, turn error-messaging on and see if there is a "headers already send"-warning, which indicates that your php-script echoed some whitespace before the header("...")-codeline.