# main.css was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

SA

I know this question already have multiple answers but none worked with me cause mine is a bit weird.

Basically I have few Pages say:

```
index.html
contacts.html
find.html

header.html // main.css files contains  styling for this header file which is dynamically loaded into different pages.
```

The problem is that when I load the header file into `index.html` or `contacts.html` it loads fine, but then when I load it at `find.html` it pops  the browser console error saying:

```
Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead[Learn More]  JquerySock.js:1
The stylesheet http://localhost:20012/Duck/main.css was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”. search
The stylesheet http://localhost:20012/Duck/CSS/search.css was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”. search
The stylesheet http://localhost:20012/Duck/mainelements/aside.css was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”.
```

Also the Request Header `content-type` happen to be as `text/css` but the response comes up as `text/html` don't really know why.
FYI: I am using Debian (Jessie). Firefox ESR v52.4.0

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your code is requiring a login to access the CSS stylesheet, and returning a HTML login page instead of the CSS.

Here 'Styles' is the folder that contains css.

```
<location path="~/Styles">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Comment: I know u copy pasted this answer. Anyway I can access my stylesheet as `http://localhost:20012/Duck/main.css` as a url link. BTW where do u put that code at?

Comment: yeah i copied.. sorry i forgot to put the link.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413107/headercontent-type-text-css-is-working-in-firefox-and-chrome-but-in-inter

@Whatever .. have a look at this both..

http://galleryproject.org/node/27061