# Are there any browser compatibility issues with not having a `.js` postifx to served JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

Is there any issue with having my JavaScript files being served from urls that look like

```
http://example.com/file
```

rather than

```
http://example.com/file.js
```

I know it's not a big deal, but it's still nice to know.

Thank you.

Comment: As long as you serve it with the correct mimetype, it should be okay.

Comment: I would only caution that setting mime-type or content-type may prove difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file extension should not pose any problem but nevertheless some browsers mights issue a warning if the file will not be served with a proper MIME type: "application/javascript"

Answer (score 2):

No. Nothing (common or sane) cares about file extensions in URIs (because there aren't any, just things that look like them).

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not *entirely* true. For example, all major browsers appear to execute JavaScript in documents served with an arbitrary content type if their extension is `.htm` or `.html`. ([related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741438/what-content-types-execute-javascript-in-the-browser)) Still, true in this case of course